# Arduino Serial Monitor responde caracteres Especiales con comandos AT Bluetooth HC-05

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, línea-de-comandos

Estoy recibiendo caracteres especiales al enviar cualquier comando. El comando que envie en la imagen fue el "AT" y me arrojo esos caracteres raros. He intentado varias cosas, una fue cambiar el baud rate, intente usar lo mismo con un arduino MEGA y UNO y diferentes cables, pero siempre salen caracteres especiales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa la velocidad en baudios del serial que usas para el BT. Regularmente es de 9600, igual que el Serial por Hardware. Veo que estás usando 38400. ¿Configuraste tu HC-05 a esa velocidad?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de configurar la velocidad del IDE arduino donde programas tu codigo arduino a la misma frecuencia que tu serial ejemplo 9600, puedes configurar la velocidad del serial con este comando `Serial.begin(115200);`

Comment: Bienvenido. Gracias por tu contribución pero ese no ese el problema ya que se ve claramente el mensaje "Enter AT commands".  Si prestas atención el problema era el que indica la otra respuesta.